# PHP For Each Loop Outputs twice as much as it should

Tags: php, mysql

I am running the below code to echo the contents of a single row from the MySQL database and it is currently outputting what seems to be twice the output. See below

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE this='1'") or die(mysql_error()); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    foreach($row as $key => $field) {
        if($key != 'id' && $key != 'doss' && $key != ''){
            echo "Field name: $key = $field<br />";
            $missing =$missing+$field;
        }
     }
```

The output is:

```
Field name: 1 = 0
Field name: go = 0
Field name: 2 = 1
Field name: het = 1
Field name: 3 = 0
Field name: quf = 0
Field name: 4 = 0
Field name: sid = 0
Field name: 5 = 1
Field name: ram = 1
Field name: 6 = 1
```

Comment: Please be aware that the `mysql_xx()` functions are considered obsolete and not recommended for use. The PHP manual strongly recommends switching to either the equivalent `mysqli_xx()` functions or the PDO library.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_array` will produce an array with both numerical keys and associative keys.

The default definition is:

```
array mysql_fetch_array ( resource $result [, int $result_type = MYSQL_BOTH ] )
```

If you want to get unique values, use either `MYSQL_ASSOC` or `MYSQL_NUM`

Comment: Cheers. You have taught me how to fix this problem and saved me having to ask what the difference between mysql_fetch_array and mysql_fetch_assoc is

Comment: @max No problem! And don't forget that using mysql_ methods is discouraged. Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: Why is that? Looks like I have something else to research ;)

Comment: @Max http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php Look at the big red box :)

Answer (score 3):

`mysql_fetch_array` by default returns an array that contains both a numeric index, and associative keys.

If you want one or the other, you can pass in extra options:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM);
```

or

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

BTW, go PDO! :)

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_assoc` is the function you are looking for